# Removing a member of a Google Play Beta Test

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to remove a member from my Google Play beta test group in the developer console?  I have removed them from my Google+ Community and when the user checks their G+ communites mine is not listed.  However, when they go to the store and search for my app, they still see and download the beta version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The user will need to leave the test.  They do this by going to the link that you originally provided (i.e the link that they used to enter the test) and clicking "Leave the Test."

Comment: This is correct, however, I had to invite the user back to the test/community for them to be able to click on "Leave the test."  Thank you

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense at all - I can confirm that you need to invite the users again, but it doesn't make sense, because if I want to remove beta testers from my beta tester group, they shouldn't have to opt out on their own... think I'm gonna contact Google about this - this doesn't make sense. I now have about 40 beta testers "caught in limbo", because they were removed from the G+ community and now still get all the beta versions which is pointing towards a test server...

Comment: hi, what's the current situation?

Comment: Please tell me this is not still the case because it seems like it is. Users have to remove themselves from the test group? As an app developer, I have no way to force remove people from the beta group? Even clicking the big "Disable Beta Testing" button doesn't change users already in the beta group?! That's ridiculous.

Comment: Totally agree! Google Alpha/Beta is a poorly designed experience, seriously lacking mechanisms to control the flow of testers and access to your app. Other things lacking is the ridiculous time it takes for each new version to get distributed and getting the "public" version of an app back in google play after you leave the testing program. I am shocked that a company as rich and skilled as Google can't figure this out.

Comment: @Carl It's coming to the end of 2020, and it's still a problem.

Answer (score 11):

While logged-in to the Google account that you'd like to leave the BETA program, hit the following URL (replacing "your.package.name" with your APK's package name)

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/your.package.name/leave

You can also send the BETA tester this link.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved a problem that in order to leave the program a user would otherwise have to use the original Beta enrollment URL they got in the mail.
And not all users, even including the app developer :-() might retain such messages for extended times.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I could do was to close the Beta track for my app. This is the `Remove Testers` button inside the manage beta page. I still don't see a way to remove individuals from the beta test.