# How to invite Google Play Console internal testers

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, google-play-console

Releasing an app on Play Console has several release steps: internal testing > closed alpha > open beta > production

I'm in internal testing phase, but no one on my testers list has been given an invite. I created the list, including my email and another that I know is valid, both Gmail accounts, but no email invite. There is an option to "save" after managing testers, but there is no "send invite"  button. All I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: when tester accept the invitation for internal testing and when they give feedback how we can find it. it mean where we can find the feedback

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The system doesn't invite them, you have to give them the opt-in URL yourself. I think the email list is just for access control.

The [Google Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) details this step:

> After clicking the opt-in link, your testers will get an explanation of what it means to be a tester and a link to opt in. Each tester needs to opt in using the link.

Comment: I'll wait for someone else to chime in to verify that. If that's the case... it seems really non-intuitive -__-

Comment: Where is the opt-out URL?

Comment: @smilebomb ye this whole publishing interface is built REALLLY badly. What amazes me is how Google have this rigorous developer on-boarding process for potential employess yet they can't get basic UI right.

Comment: I don´t understand how this questions helps, I came here from that link exactly. Where is the option to get the opt-in link? The link you share doesn´t say that.

Comment: @AlejandroCasanova if you look closely, you can see the opt-in link pictured on the UI (in the question).

Comment: @greeble31 , but what if I got no link there yet? I have made releases for both Alpha and Closed Track, but still no link in that "Opt-in URL" line ...

Comment: @HX_unbanned Not sure, I thought it always appeared immediately.

Comment: @greeble31 , hmm .. can you please then verify that you only built apk, uploaded to the internal testing track and after while you got the link? Or you did something else/more?

Comment: @HX_unbanned Sorry, can't verify that, it's been too long since I did this.

Comment: Go to "App releases" then "internal test track" then "manage
Manage testers" then click "expand": the "Opt-in URL" appears!

Comment: @user1505520 the opt-out url is the same as the opt-in url, it should have been specified somewhere I guess, hopefully I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389149/removing-a-member-of-a-google-play-beta-test)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Go to "App releases"
2. then "internal test track"
3. then "manage Manage testers"
4. then click "expand"
5. the "Opt-in URL" appears as in the image below
6. send the link to all testers, they'll be able to "join the programme"

[image: Opt-in URL appears in the Manage testers block]

Comment: Important to note that they can only "Join the programme" if they are signed in with their Google account and you have already added their Google account address to the list of testers.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem today. I added myself to the internal testing and waited for the email, it never came. There's no indication on the web page or documentation that it is supposed to come.

BTW, I've had great success with Fabric Beta for distributing test versions of my apps before. I've also been involved with a project that uses Microsoft's App Center -- that seems to work pretty well too.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the mailing list wasn't checked, I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same issue and what I did the followings:
Option 1: I sent the Google Play app link: by which they can directly go and download the Internal Tester version

Option 2: And, I manually sent them the .apk file which they manually downloaded and install. And the internal testers are happy with it.

**NOTE:** Try option2 only if Option-1 does not work.